# How Do I Override X-Forwarded-Proto and X-Forwarded-Port So Rels Are Properly Calculated?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, spring-data-rest

I'm running SDR 2.6.4 in AWS and have a situation where the rels are not being properly calculated.

I have an API Gateway proxying calls to an Application Load Balancer which forwards calls to SDR.  The AGW terminates the TLS connection, talking to the ALB over plain HTTP and non-standard port.

The URLs looks something like this:

*https://apigateway:443/foo -> http://loadbalancer:9876/foo*.

The rels that get calculated are a hybrid of the two: *http://apigateway:9876/bar*.

The cause is that the ALB fills in the *X-Forwarded-Proto* and *X-Forwarded-Port* with the values it was called with, not what the AGW was called with, and the *UriComponentsBuilder* uses those values to calculate the rels.

My initial thought was to create a *HandlerInterceptor* and force those values but quickly discovered that *HttpServletRequest* does not allow for mutation of HTTP headers.

Watching things in the debugger leads me to believe that once Tomcat hands off the HTTP request object, it is fully formed and Spring can't do anything to modify it.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I could add/modify the forward headers to point at the AGW and not the ALB?

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you state, you cannot modify the HttpServletRequest however you can wrap it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html

Via a Servlet filter then rather than via a Spring interceptor you should be able to do something like:

Wrapper:

```
public class MyRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper{

    public MyRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request){
        super(request);
    }

    @Override 
    public String getHeaders(String name){
        if(name.equals("X-Forwarded-Proto"){
            return "xyz";
        }
        else{
            return ((HttpServletRequest)getRequest()).getHeaders(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Filter:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter{

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        chain.doFilter(new MyRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest)request), response);
    }
}
```